# React Native - Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module

Tags: react-native, react-native-gifted-chat

I get error `Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module` whenever I upgrade above react-native `0.61.5`.  Once I downgrade back to `0.61.5` it works fine again.

UPDATE 11/14/20
I tried the answer `killall -9 node` but I get the error `bash: killall: command not found`.  This is likely a very rookie mistake where I need to install something or run command from different path

UPDATE 12/28/20 - in response to @dhruv soni.....below is my index.js file where `AppRegistry.registerComponent` is called:

UPDATE 01/23/21 - I used "React Native Upgrade Helper" to upgrade...triple checked everything is correct.
Issue only occurs on Android (not IOS)....but it builds fine on Android Studio...error only occurs with `react-native run-android`.
I use very many 3rd party libraries so Im guessing its related to that

Comment: You update to 0.61.5 and get error. But down to 0.61.5 it work?
Wait. Are you kidding me xD

Comment: Did you restart node after upgraded? Maybe try `yarn start --reset-cache`.

Comment: Yes I tried npm start --reset-cache

Comment: Can you please show your index file where you are calling AppRegistry.registerComponent function

Comment: Try this `npx react-native start --reset-cache`

Comment: npx react-native start --reset-cache doesnt work either

Comment: Are you getting this error when running an ios app or android app, or both. I think the problem may not be with your JS. but somewhere deeper.

Comment: I forgot to ask that, how do you upgrade react native to a newer version?

Comment: Hi @Lukasz - error only occurs with Android....not IOS
I upgraded RN using "React Native Upgrade Helper"....Ive triple checked its all done correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue on my end by double checking that i modified all the files correctly during my [RN upgrade](https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper), then running `watchman watch-del-all`, and `react-native start --reset-cache`. Then on android, build -> clean. then it worked! sigh

### Specific solution of your question

I found a wrong initialization of appContainer. you can fix as below

```
const AppContainer = createAppContainer(SignedInTabNav);

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: @jamesmurphy can you share reproducible examples on git?. so I can fix it for you

Comment: thanks so much.....I created minimized version of app in following git repo:  https://github.com/jamesdmurphy51/sandox.git

Comment: @jamesmurphy did you check my updated answer?

Answer (score 0):

I can be wrong but in my case, this happens every time whenever I install new npm package and maybe not sure but I face this only with iOS, so each time whenever I face this issue I follow these steps.

- killall -9 node
- delete package-lock.json
- delete node_module folder
- delete pods folder
- delete pod-lock file.
- npm i
- npm pod-install ios
- npm start --reset-cache
- react-native run-ios

Comment: Yes I did something similar......delete entire project then re-clone from GH so have a complete clean slate.....didnt solve issue!!

Answer (score -1):

Kill all node process and start the server and run the application

- Run command `killall node`
- Run `taskkill /f /im node.exe` if the process still persists
- Run command `yarn start --reset-cache`
- Run command `react-native run-ios` OR `react-native run-android`

Comment: This is likely a very rooky comment....but where do I run command "killall -9 node"?
I get the error "bash: killall: command not found"

Comment: Its the `killall` command that my (visual studio code) terminal does not understand.....doesnt matter if I try `killall node` or `killall -9 node` I get the same error `bash: killall: command not found`

Answer (score -1):

I see now why noone could answer this....

I had to comment out nearly all code in my app...piece by piece until the error stopped occuring.
The naughty line of code was `import {GiftedChat, Bubble} from 'react-native-gifted-chat'`

Seems there is some kind of conflict between my upgraded version of RN and RNGiftedChat

```
"react-native": "0.63.3",
"react-native-gifted-chat": "^0.16.3",
```

Can "fix" bug by either:

1. downgrade RN
   or
2. Remove/replace react-native-gifted-chat.
   .....however dont really want to do either.

...not really sure where to go from here

Comment: https://prnt.sc/xmzvjf but you post answer same like me before and then deleted

Comment: Yes - I created a very slimmed down version of my app to provide to you on gitHub....and I realized I created a syntax error while creating the slimmed down version.....that error was not related to the original issue that I answered above.  Despite this I have marked your answer as correct (as it was the correct answer to my incorrect question)...upvoted the answer and awarded you with the 200 bounty (as I appreciate the efforts you went to)